# How to check if a chest contains a certain Item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been trying to get this command to trigger when I have a piece of dirt in the first slot but it hasn't worked.

```
/execute if block ~ ~ ~ minecraft:chest{Items:[{id:"dirt",Slot:0,Count:1}]} run say hi
```

I've tried this so far but it just won't work. Any ideas?

Edit: There's another post with an answer but it uses /testforblock which isn't a valid command anymore.

Comment: it's worth looking at the other answers on that question - there's one specifically for 1.13+.